# Apk not found in alpine

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I am trying to setup gitlab-ci and having problems to run it.

I am trying to do as simple pipeline as possible, that just compiles all files in repo and runs tests as second stage. this is my gitlab-ci so far:

```
image: alpine:latest

build:
  script:
  - apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base \
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

when pipeline starts I get:

/bin/sh: eval: line 49:  apk: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if this is stupid question but I am trying to do such thing for a first time :) .

Comment: You assume that `apk` is available on path; is it so for the base image?

Comment: no idea all I know is that runner has default `alpine3.7` installed

Comment: This is weird, `apk` should be on `PATH`. What do you get when you run `which apk` as the first script command?

Comment: BTW Python 3 is provided by package `python3` (and `python3-dev` for development files), not `python`. Actually there's no package `python`, that's just alternative name for `python2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify python image. I splitted the commands and got better error.